# Flutter - Flip animation - Flip a card over its right or left side based on the tap's location

Tags: flutter, flutter-animation

I've started playing with Flutter and now thinking about the best way how I can implement a card's flipping animation.

I found this [flip_card](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/flip_card) package and I'm trying to adjust [its source code](https://github.com/fedeoo/flip_card) to my needs.

Here is the app which I have now:

```
import 'dart:math';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(FlipAnimationApp());

class FlipAnimationApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text("Flip animation"),
        ),
        body: Center(
          child: Container(
            width: 200,
            height: 200,
            child: WidgetFlipper(
              frontWidget: Container(
                color: Colors.green[200],
                child: Center(
                  child: Text(
                    "FRONT side.",
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              backWidget: Container(
                color: Colors.yellow[200],
                child: Center(
                  child: Text(
                    "BACK side.",
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class WidgetFlipper extends StatefulWidget {
  WidgetFlipper({
    Key key,
    this.frontWidget,
    this.backWidget,
  }) : super(key: key);

  final Widget frontWidget;
  final Widget backWidget;

  @override
  _WidgetFlipperState createState() => _WidgetFlipperState();
}

class _WidgetFlipperState extends State<WidgetFlipper> with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {
  AnimationController controller;
  Animation<double> _frontRotation;
  Animation<double> _backRotation;
  bool isFrontVisible = true;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    controller = AnimationController(duration: Duration(milliseconds: 500), vsync: this);
    _frontRotation = TweenSequence(
      <TweenSequenceItem<double>>[
        TweenSequenceItem<double>(
          tween: Tween(begin: 0.0, end: pi / 2).chain(CurveTween(curve: Curves.linear)),
          weight: 50.0,
        ),
        TweenSequenceItem<double>(
          tween: ConstantTween<double>(pi / 2),
          weight: 50.0,
        ),
      ],
    ).animate(controller);
    _backRotation = TweenSequence(
      <TweenSequenceItem<double>>[
        TweenSequenceItem<double>(
          tween: ConstantTween<double>(pi / 2),
          weight: 50.0,
        ),
        TweenSequenceItem<double>(
          tween: Tween(begin: -pi / 2, end: 0.0).chain(CurveTween(curve: Curves.linear)),
          weight: 50.0,
        ),
      ],
    ).animate(controller);
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    controller.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Stack(
      fit: StackFit.expand,
      children: [
        AnimatedCard(
          animation: _backRotation,
          child: widget.backWidget,
        ),
        AnimatedCard(
          animation: _frontRotation,
          child: widget.frontWidget,
        ),
        _tapDetectionControls(),
      ],
    );
  }

  Widget _tapDetectionControls() {
    return Stack(
      fit: StackFit.expand,
      children: <Widget>[
        GestureDetector(
          onTap: _leftRotation,
          child: FractionallySizedBox(
            widthFactor: 0.5,
            heightFactor: 1.0,
            alignment: Alignment.topLeft,
            child: Container(
              color: Colors.transparent,
            ),
          ),
        ),
        GestureDetector(
          onTap: _rightRotation,
          child: FractionallySizedBox(
            widthFactor: 0.5,
            heightFactor: 1.0,
            alignment: Alignment.topRight,
            child: Container(
              color: Colors.transparent,
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }

  void _leftRotation() {
    _toggleSide();
  }

  void _rightRotation() {
    _toggleSide();
  }

  void _toggleSide() {
    if (isFrontVisible) {
      controller.forward();
      isFrontVisible = false;
    } else {
      controller.reverse();
      isFrontVisible = true;
    }
  }
}

class AnimatedCard extends StatelessWidget {
  AnimatedCard({
    this.child,
    this.animation,
  });

  final Widget child;
  final Animation<double> animation;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return AnimatedBuilder(
      animation: animation,
      builder: (BuildContext context, Widget child) {
        var transform = Matrix4.identity();
        transform.setEntry(3, 2, 0.001);
        transform.rotateY(animation.value);
        return Transform(
          transform: transform,
          alignment: Alignment.center,
          child: child,
        );
      },
      child: child,
    );
  }
}
```

Here is how it looks like:

[image]

What I'd like to achieve is **to make the card flip over its right side if it was tapped on its right half and over its left side if it was tapped on its left half. If it is tapped several times in a row on the same half it should flip over the same side (not back and forth as it is doing now).**

So the desired animation should behave as the following one from Quizlet app.
[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should know when you tap on the right or left to change the animations dynamically, for that you could use a flag `isRightTap`. Then, you should invert the values of the `Tweens` if it has to rotate to one side or to the other.

And the side you should rotate would be:

- Rotate to left if the front is visible and you tapped on the left, or, because the back animation is reversed, if the back is is visible and you tapped on the right
- Otherwise, rotate to right

Here are the things I changed in `_WidgetFlipperState` from the code in the question:

```
_updateRotations(bool isRightTap) {
  setState(() {
    bool rotateToLeft = (isFrontVisible && !isRightTap) || !isFrontVisible && isRightTap;
    _frontRotation = TweenSequence(
      <TweenSequenceItem<double>>[
        TweenSequenceItem<double>(
          tween: Tween(begin: 0.0, end: rotateToLeft ? (pi / 2) : (-pi / 2))
              .chain(CurveTween(curve: Curves.linear)),
          weight: 50.0,
        ),
        TweenSequenceItem<double>(
          tween: ConstantTween<double>(rotateToLeft ? (-pi / 2) : (pi / 2)),
          weight: 50.0,
        ),
      ],
    ).animate(controller);
    _backRotation = TweenSequence(
      <TweenSequenceItem<double>>[
        TweenSequenceItem<double>(
          tween: ConstantTween<double>(rotateToLeft ? (pi / 2) : (-pi / 2)),
          weight: 50.0,
        ),
        TweenSequenceItem<double>(
          tween: Tween(begin: rotateToLeft ? (-pi / 2) : (pi / 2), end: 0.0)
              .chain(CurveTween(curve: Curves.linear)),
          weight: 50.0,
        ),
      ],
    ).animate(controller);
  });
}

@override
void initState() {
  super.initState();
  controller =
      AnimationController(duration: Duration(milliseconds: 500), vsync: this);
  _updateRotations(true);
}

void _leftRotation() {
  _toggleSide(false);
}

void _rightRotation() {
  _toggleSide(true);
}

void _toggleSide(bool isRightTap) {
  _updateRotations(isRightTap);
  if (isFrontVisible) {
    controller.forward();
    isFrontVisible = false;
  } else {
    controller.reverse();
    isFrontVisible = true;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

[image]

```
import 'dart:math';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return const MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: MyHomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyHomePage();

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  bool _toggler = true;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(actions: [
        TextButton(
          onPressed: _onFlipCardPressed,
          child: const Text('change', style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white)),
        )
      ]),
      body: Center(
        child: SizedBox.square(
          dimension: 140,
          child: FlipCard(
            toggler: _toggler,
            frontCard: AppCard(title: 'Front'),
            backCard: AppCard(title: 'Back'),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  void _onFlipCardPressed() {
    setState(() {
      _toggler = !_toggler;
    });
  }
}

class AppCard extends StatelessWidget {
  final String title;

  const AppCard({
    required this.title,
  });

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return DecoratedBox(
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20.0),
        color: Colors.deepPurple[400],
      ),
      child: Center(
        child: Text(
          title,
          style: const TextStyle(
            fontSize: 40.0,
            color: Colors.white,
          ),
          textAlign: TextAlign.center,
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class FlipCard extends StatelessWidget {
  final bool toggler;
  final Widget frontCard;
  final Widget backCard;

  const FlipCard({
    required this.toggler,
    required this.backCard,
    required this.frontCard,
  });

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return GestureDetector(
      child: AnimatedSwitcher(
        duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 800),
        transitionBuilder: _transitionBuilder,
        layoutBuilder: (widget, list) => Stack(children: [widget!, ...list]),
        switchInCurve: Curves.ease,
        switchOutCurve: Curves.ease.flipped,
        child: toggler
            ? SizedBox(key: const ValueKey('front'), child: frontCard)
            : SizedBox(key: const ValueKey('back'), child: backCard),
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget _transitionBuilder(Widget widget, Animation<double> animation) {
    final rotateAnimation = Tween(begin: pi, end: 0.0).animate(animation);
    return AnimatedBuilder(
      animation: rotateAnimation,
      child: widget,
      builder: (context, widget) {
        final isFront = ValueKey(toggler) == widget!.key;
        final rotationY = isFront ? rotateAnimation.value : min(rotateAnimation.value, pi * 0.5);
        return Transform(
          transform: Matrix4.rotationY(rotationY)..setEntry(3, 0, 0),
          alignment: Alignment.center,
          child: widget,
        );
      },
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: good. It's work for me. Thanks. Dont using AnimationController, because in some cases your interface will be backwards. It's only true for simple UI (buttons, photos)

Answer (score 0):

Try this code I've made some changes to your code, now the `GestureDetector` is divided equally in width on widget so when you tap on the left side of the box it will reverse the animation and if you tap on right side part it will forward the animation.

```
 Widget _tapDetectionControls() {
    return Flex(
      direction: Axis.horizontal,
      children: <Widget>[
        Expanded(
          flex: 1,
          child: GestureDetector(
            onTap: _leftRotation,
          ),
        ),
        Expanded(
          flex: 1,
          child: GestureDetector(
            onTap: _rightRotation,
          ),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }

  void _leftRotation() {
    controller.reverse();
  }

  void _rightRotation() {
    controller.forward();
  }
```

Comment: I've tried a similar approach, but it doesn't work/cover my needs: Case 1. If you tap on the right side of the card, it will flip it, but if you tap on the right side again, it won't do anything as the animation is in its end state already. Case 2. If you open the app and tap on the left side of the card, if won't flip since the animation in its start phase and reverse won't take effect. Any suggestions?

Comment: okay, so when we click on the right side card should flip in forward and when we click on the left side it should flip reverse, no matter is it first or last? Correct ??

Comment: Yep, that's the behavior I'd like to achieve.

Comment: I tried this scenario, so in this, we need two animations for both of 2 widgets, which should be changed dynamically. I'll try to crack this and will let you know.

Comment: I've come to the same conclusion, but I don't have enough skills in Flutter for now to solve it in an elegant way :)