# how to fix mirror effect while animate widget in flutter

Tags: flutter, animation, flutter-getx

I try build a 3d animation with getX. It is working fine except for a minor issue. When the animation finishes, it behaves as if there is a mirror and flips the image according to the axis it rotated. How can I solve this situation where it is showing symmetry with respect to the axis on which the animation takes place (clearly visible in the gif file)?

My animation controller below

```
`class SevkiyatBilgiAnimasyonController extends GetxController with GetSingleTickerProviderStateMixin {

  late AnimationController animationController;
  late Animation<double> animation;
  AnimationStatus animationStatus = AnimationStatus.dismissed;

  @override
  void onInit() {
    animationController = AnimationController(
      duration: Duration(milliseconds: 1000),
      vsync: this,
    )/* ..addListener(() {
        if (animationController.isCompleted) {
          animationController.repeat();
        }
        return update();
      }) */;


    animation = Tween(begin: 0.00, end:1.0)
        .animate(animationController)
      ..addListener(() => update())..addStatusListener((status) {
         animationStatus=status;
       });   
    super.onInit();
  }
}`
```

And my Widget ;

```
return Scaffold(
          body: Center(
            child: SingleChildScrollView(
              child: Column(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                children: <Widget>[
                  // _buildTextField(),
                  const SizedBox(
                    height: 20,
                  ),
                  GetBuilder(
                    init: SevkiyatBilgiAnimasyonController(),
                    builder: (controller) {
                      return Transform(
                        alignment: Alignment.center,
                        transform: Matrix4.identity()
                          ..setEntry(3, 2, 0.0005)
                          ..rotateY(pi *
                              _animasyonController.animation.value),
                        child: Card(
                          child:
                              _animasyonController.animation.value <=
                                      0.5
                                  ? Container(
                                      color: Colors.red,
                                      width: 240,
                                      height: 240,
                                      child: Center(
                                        child: Text(
                                          "R",
                                          style: TextStyle(
                                              fontSize: 50,
                                              color: Colors.white),
                                        ),
                                      ),
                                    )
                                  : Container(
                                      color: Colors.grey,
                                      width: 240,
                                      height: 240,
                                      child: Center(
                                        child: Text(
                                          "F",
                                          style: TextStyle(
                                              fontSize: 50,
                                              color: Colors.white),
                                        ),
                                      ),
                                    ),
                        ),
                      );
                    },
                  ),
                  ElevatedButton(
                    onPressed: () {
                      if (_animasyonController.animationStatus ==
                          AnimationStatus.dismissed) {
                        _animasyonController.animationController.forward();
                      } else {
                        _animasyonController.animationController.reverse();
                      }
                    },
                    child: Text("Animation test"),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
        );
```

And it is a gif of my problem

[image]

Comment: here is a medium blog where it does exact same thing: https://medium.com/flutter-community/flutter-flip-card-animation-eb25c403f371

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Flutter - Flip animation - Flip a card over its right or left side based on the tap's location](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54958897/flutter-flip-animation-flip-a-card-over-its-right-or-left-side-based-on-the)

Answer (score 0):

It looks correct to me: you are rotating the `Card`, therefore when it's beyond 180° you're watching it from its back and the text looks horizontally flipped.

This is how it works now:

```
straight R → (reverse R)

(straight F) → reverse F
```

What you were trying to do, instead, is replacing a red "R" `Card` with a gray "F" `Card`, but the second card should be rotated 180° with respect to the first one, so that *after the rotation* it looks straight. You should, for example, put another Transform around the gray "F" `Card` applying a constant 180° rotation to it (constant, not depending on the animation's state).

This is how you want it to be:

```
straight R → (reverse R)

(reverse F) → straight F
```